# Jenkins Cloudformation plugin- no updates are to be performed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, aws-cloudformation

I am using Jenkins with AWS CloudFormation plugin to create stacks.

**My current setup in Jenkins:**

Jenkins job 1 - create cloudformation stack1 with build Trigger with Poll SCM

Jenkins job 2 - create cloudformation stack2 with build after job 1

Jenkins job 3 - create cloudformation stack3 with build after job 2

**Issue:**

Jenkins job to create a cloudformation stack failed with following error on failed job console output:

*Reason: Detailed Message: No updates are to be performed. (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError;)*

**Desired result**

How to get all jobs run successfully.
When there is a change on jenkins job 1 and job 3 but no change on job 2 or likewise.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about getting rid of the Jenkins plugin and just using the AWS CLI?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html

The above command should exit successfully if there is a change or not.

Comment: Thanks Davis. That could be an option, will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Jenkins plugin but you need to exec the create change set call then check results and then conditionally execute the changeset if it has changes instead

Comment: You mean setup a pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You may create 3 different projects for individual jobs. 
In Project1's post build action choose option "trigger only if build is stable".Project1 will trigger Project2 after complete its jobs.
In Project2's post build action, choose option "trigger even if build fails".
Project2 will trigger Project3 after complete its jobs.
By this approach you will be able to trigger three jobs individually. Project3 will triggered by Project2 even if it's marked as failed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! by using AWS CLI for cloudformation as shell script.